# Bundle Perl XUL::Gui application

Tags: perl, user-interface

I am starting to look at XUL::Gui as a means of building a front end to a pre-existing Perl application, before I dive into all the doc I want to check how I would deliver all this.  So far in the doc I can see I have to start my example from the command line, which launches a Perl server and a browser.  A few questions:

1. How to launch the program from a GUI (and an icon to start up the GUI) as per usual programs, which launches the Perl server in the background, so that all that comes up is the browser?  Would this also launch the Terminal/ command line too - that should be suppressed, so how to do that?
2. Is it possible to name the browser something "Here is your application" so that it is clear that is the new application that users should be looking at, not another browswer window they have open.
3. How to bundle it up for delivery - can all the above be done in PAR (I've never used PAR, I just see that it is the common answer for this question).

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup a graphical operating system level link to the perl script, which will execute it in the background:  `perl myscript.pl > /dev/null 2>&1 &`. This is the same way you would launch a program written with another toolkit.  There should be an option when creating the link to hide the terminal window.  You can also pass `display` the pair `silent => 1` to turn off any status messages that the toolkit produces.
2. You can name the browser window by setting the `title` attribute of the window:

   ```
   display Window(
       title => 'my window title',
       ... # additional window attributes and children
   );
   ```

   Setting a custom window icon will be a feature in an upcoming release.
3. I have not tried using one of the packers with XUL::Gui, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.  The script will still have a dependency upon Firefox or XULRunner being installed.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately step 3 is starting to cause something of a nightmare.  Am simply trying to bundle your standard example (before I get into my own application, want to make sure the equivalent of hello world works for the whole chain).  However, looks like packaging perl has its own (very steep) learning curve.

Comment: Hi Eric, notwithstanding possible problems down the line I am starting to look at using XUL::Gui in more depth.  So have just run all your examples - and have to say it looks quite awesome!  One thing that my app will have to do is to stay alive provided it is not explicitly closed down.  I just adapted your most basic example, but one thing I noticed after leaving the application for a few hours (Mac fell asleep) is that the server went away, although the browser window was left alive.  So the application no longer responded. Is this common?  What can I do to avoid this sort of behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you use PAR, you can use a shortcut on windows or make an application bundle on Mac.  You can suppress the terminal window that shows up with PAR.
2. Looks like this was answered
3. PAR!  Par really works well.  You may need to explicitly include libraries and via the [command line par packer options](https://metacpan.org/module/pp).

   On Mac, use [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to package your PAR as an application bundle, this really works well to distribute perl applications on the Mac.